# Xamarin, Android: How does this "ListView Adapter" work?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

So, I'm working on this app with a chat included. I downloaded a sample and I am trying to change the layout. But this somehow doesnt work. There is another layout that is called listview adapter and I dont know what it does but I think it it somehow connected with the problem. THis is the original LayOut (only a list and a button and a edittext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.refractored.fab.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

    />

  <EditText
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Your message"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    />

  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/fab"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_of_messages"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the ListView adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/message_user"
    android:textStyle="normal|bold"
    />


  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_user"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/message_time"

    />


  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/message_user"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/message_text"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code for the LIstView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
using Android.Content;

namespace XamarinChatApp
{
    internal class ListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter
    {
        private List<MessageContent> lstMessage;
        private MainActivity mainActivity;

        public ListViewAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, List<MessageContent> lstMessage)
        {
            this.mainActivity = mainActivity;
            this.lstMessage = lstMessage;
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get
            {
                return lstMessage.Count;
            }
        }

        public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mainActivity.BaseContext.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService);
            View itemView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.List_Item, null);

            TextView message_user, message_time, message_content;
            message_user = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message_user);
            message_content = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message_text);
            message_time = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.message_time);

            message_user.Text = lstMessage[position].Email;
            message_time.Text = lstMessage[position].Time;
            message_content.Text = lstMessage[position].Message;

            return itemView;
        }
    }
}
```

Why cant I change the first LayOut? And What execalty does this ListView adapter do? Are those related? To me, it only looks like this is formatting the inside of the list. But I dont see the connection...

THANKS :)

Comment: "this somehow doesnt work" is not clear. What kind of changes are you looking to implement? Are you having any exception?

Answer (score 0):

The first layout gives the overall layout for the page.

The second layout gives the layout for each item i.e each individual message(username,message,time).

Now you pass all the data to the listview adapter and this displays each message one by one. The listview adapter only inflates the 2nd layout one by one.

The codefor the listview is the standard code for an adpater which returns the count,position,item and the inflated view.